# Prices in output of batch auction

Tags: cow-protocol

It is specified that the solution to a batch auction must include a field called `prices`: https://docs.cow.fi/off-chain-services/in-depth-solver-specification/output-batch-auction-solutions#prices-of-the-traded-tokens

It is unclear to me though:

1. To which tokens these prices should be provided for. I assume we need to provide them for all the buy tokens for the orders we solve?
2. What are these prices? Are they the execution price but in terms of WETH? How does one compute them?

Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT

I am adding this example where I still don't understand the situation 100%:

```
  "prices": {
    "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48": "629146635278481960296630859",
    "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2": "1000000000000000000",
    "0x5a98fcbea516cf06857215779fd812ca3bef1b32": "1130493547205052"
  },
```

This snippet out of a solution comes from a USDC -> LDO order. The solution provides prices for WETH, USDC and LDO (WETH being the reference). The USDC and LDO prices match the executed amounts from the solution.

But my question is: **where does one get USDC/WETH or LDO/WETH prices from?**

In order to provide the prices as in the snippet at least one of the two prices are required, if I understand correctly. Can the solver choose a `USDC/WETH` price from an oracle, and then compute `LDO/WETH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **prices** vector is the so-called uniform clearing prices that all user orders will follow. In particular, a solver needs to provide one price for each token traded by a user order (i.e., both sell and buy token), and then the smart contract uses these prices to compute the traded amounts.

E.g., for a standard fill-or-kill sell market order, the sell amount is fixed by the user, and then the executed buy amount that the user will receive is equal to

**sell_amount * price(sell_token) / price(buy_token)**.

The analogous formula is used for buy orders.

In other words, these prices specify the exchange rates that will be used to execute the user orders. Note that AMM interactions and liquidity orders do NOT need to follow these exchange rates.

With this in mind, one can see that the price vector is scale invariant. So, it is a just a convention what token will get a price of 1, or in other words what is the unit of measure for these prices. For simplicity, one could set p(1 wei) = 10^18, in order to allow for enough accuracy, and then all other prices are with respect to this. But, this is just a convention, and solvers can use some other scaling, as, again, we are only interested in ratios of these prices and not in their absolute values.

Hope that answers your questions.

**Update:** Regarding the example you give in your edit. The price for WETH in the vector is actually not needed. Some solvers tend to always provide a price for WETH as well, but since is not traded by any user order, its price is not needed. For this particular case, and in case you indeed want to have a price for WETH as a normalization price, you can do the following:

1. Define the price of WETH as 10^18
2. Using the external prices vector that is provided in the instance.json file that describes the batch auction, and set the price of USDC according to the exchange rate suggested by the external prices. E.g. p(USDC) / p(WETH) = external_price(USDC) / external_price(WETH).
3. Then, specify the price of LDO according to the exchange rate you computed among LDO and USDC, and the price of USDC that computed in step (2).

As a clarification, the external prices vector is just an indicator of prices, and its main usage is to aggregate surplus in the objective function and denominate everything in ETH.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Hi Haris, thanks for the answer it definitely was helpful. I think there is still something missing in my understanding. I edited the question adding one extra section